# Asterisk modify headers

Tags: header, asterisk

I want to replace my SPA2102 for asterisk. How can I modify headers, like From, To and Contact?
I need to replace headers, like

```
From: "asterisk" <sip:XXXX174264@ip.ip.ip.6>;tag=as1ea48bca
```

To headers, like SPA2102.

My SPA2102 sends it like

```
"XXXX174264" <sip:XXXX174264@ip.ip.ip.6>
```

How

```
#  tcpdump -nAieth0 port 5060 and net ip.ip.ip.0/24

10:47:55.801914 IP 10.37.93.21.5060 > ip.ip.ip.6.5060: SIP, length: 906
E....j..@...
%].............INVITE sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.37.93.21:5060;branch=z9hG4bK20d7bc88
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "asterisk" <sip:XXXX174264@ip.ip.ip.6>;tag=as1ea48bca
To: <sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6>
Contact: <sip:XXXX174264@10.37.93.21:5060>
Call-ID: 6b4c893e70628a626286cd0a748f93de@ip.ip.ip.6
CSeq: 102 INVITE
User-Agent: Linksys/SPA2102-5.2.5
Date: Wed, 16 Jan 2013 04:47:55 GMT
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 333

v=0
o=- 233070007 233070007 IN IP4 10.37.93.21
s=Asterisk PBX 11.2.0
c=IN IP4 10.37.93.21
t=0 0
m=audio 10004 RTP/AVP 0 8 3 111 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
a=rtpmap:111 G726-32/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=silenceSupp:off - - - -
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

10:47:55.822359 IP ip.ip.ip.6.5060 > 10.37.93.21.5060: SIP, length: 348
E..x..@.>.#.....
%]......d.CSIP/2.0 100 Trying
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.37.93.21:5060;branch=z9hG4bK20d7bc88
From: "asterisk" <sip:XXXX174264@ip.ip.ip.6>;tag=as1ea48bca
To: <sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6>
Call-ID: 6b4c893e70628a626286cd0a748f93de@ip.ip.ip.6
CSeq: 102 INVITE
Contact: <sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6:5060>
Server: MERA MVTS3G v.4.3.0-38t
Content-Length: 0
```

I try to make call using SPA and Asterisk. Both register succes. But Asterisk can't make call.
Here is tcpdump from SPA:

```
00:58:00.778565 IP 10.37.93.23.5060 > ip.ip.ip.6.5060: SIP, length: 892
Eh..........
%].............INVITE sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.37.93.23:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-9b906813
From: XXXX174264 <sip:XXXX174264@ip.ip.ip.6>;tag=e9377d83dbc079fo0
To: <sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6>
Remote-Party-ID: XXXX174264 <sip:XXXX174264@ip.ip.ip.6>;screen=yes;party=calling
Call-ID: 27e34e53-cdeded0f@10.37.93.23
CSeq: 101 INVITE
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: XXXX174264 <sip:XXXX174264@10.37.93.23:5060>
Expires: 240
User-Agent: Linksys/SPA2102-5.2.5
Content-Length: 268
Allow: ACK, BYE, CANCEL, INFO, INVITE, NOTIFY, OPTIONS, REFER
Supported: x-sipura, replaces
Content-Type: application/sdp

v=0
o=- 93383 93383 IN IP4 10.37.93.23
s=-
c=IN IP4 10.37.93.23
t=0 0
m=audio 16186 RTP/AVP 8 0 18 4 100
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:18 G729a/8000
a=rtpmap:4 G723/8000
a=rtpmap:100 NSE/8000
a=fmtp:100 192-193
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

00:58:00.782580 IP ip.ip.ip.6.5060 > 10.37.93.23.5060: SIP, length: 342
....E..r..@.>.#.....
%]......^..SIP/2.0 100 Trying
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.37.93.23:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-9b906813
From: "XXXX174264" <sip:XXXX174264@ip.ip.ip.6>;tag=e9377d83dbc079fo0
To: <sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6>
Call-ID: 27e34e53-cdeded0f@10.37.93.23
CSeq: 101 INVITE
Contact: <sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6:5060>
Server: MERA MVTS3G v.4.3.0-38t
Content-Length: 0


00:58:02.479539 IP ip.ip.ip.6.5060 > 10.37.93.23.5060: SIP, length: 683
....E.....@.>."p....
%].......<.SIP/2.0 180 Ringing
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.37.93.23:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-9b906813
From: "XXXX174264" <sip:XXXX174264@ip.ip.ip.6>;tag=e9377d83dbc079fo0
To: <sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6>;tag=109877804-3792792162-4082950052-3026001148
Call-ID: 27e34e53-cdeded0f@10.37.93.23
CSeq: 101 INVITE
Contact: <sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Server: MERA MVTS3G v.4.3.0-38t
Content-Length:   258

v=0
o=- 1358621882 1358621882 IN IP4 ip.ip.ip.5
s=-
c=IN IP4 ip.ip.ip.5
t=0 0
m=audio 39878 RTP/AVP 8 0 18
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:18 G729/8000
a=fmtp:18 annexb=no
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv
a=silenceSupp:off - - - -

00:58:30.832778 IP 10.37.93.23.5060 > ip.ip.ip.6.5060: SIP, length: 339
Eh.o........
%]..........[O.CANCEL sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.37.93.23:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-9b906813
From: XXXX174264 <sip:XXXX174264@ip.ip.ip.6>;tag=e9377d83dbc079fo0
To: <sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6>
Call-ID: 27e34e53-cdeded0f@10.37.93.23
CSeq: 101 CANCEL
Max-Forwards: 70
User-Agent: Linksys/SPA2102-5.2.5
Content-Length: 0


00:58:30.836782 IP ip.ip.ip.6.5060 > 10.37.93.23.5060: SIP, length: 385
....E.....@.>.#.....
%].......7.SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.37.93.23:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-9b906813
From: "XXXX174264" <sip:XXXX174264@ip.ip.ip.6>;tag=e9377d83dbc079fo0
To: <sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6>;tag=109877804-3792792162-4082950052-3026001148
Call-ID: 27e34e53-cdeded0f@10.37.93.23
CSeq: 101 CANCEL
Contact: <sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6:5060>
Server: MERA MVTS3G v.4.3.0-38t
Content-Length: 0


00:58:30.838775 IP ip.ip.ip.6.5060 > 10.37.93.23.5060: SIP, length: 450
....E.....@.>.#Y....
%].........SIP/2.0 487 Request Terminated
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.37.93.23:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-9b906813
From: "XXXX174264" <sip:XXXX174264@ip.ip.ip.6>;tag=e9377d83dbc079fo0
To: <sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6>;tag=109877804-3792792162-4082950052-3026001148
Call-ID: 27e34e53-cdeded0f@10.37.93.23
CSeq: 101 INVITE
Contact: <sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6:5060>
Server: MERA MVTS3G v.4.3.0-38t
Reason: SIP;cause=487;text="Request Terminated"
Content-Length: 0


00:58:30.845777 IP 10.37.93.23.5060 > ip.ip.ip.6.5060: SIP, length: 437
Eh.........&
%].............ACK sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.37.93.23:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-9b906813
From: XXXX174264 <sip:XXXX174264@ip.ip.ip.6>;tag=e9377d83dbc079fo0
To: <sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6>;tag=109877804-3792792162-4082950052-3026001148
Call-ID: 27e34e53-cdeded0f@10.37.93.23
CSeq: 101 ACK
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: XXXX174264 <sip:XXXX174264@10.37.93.23:5060>
User-Agent: Linksys/SPA2102-5.2.5
Content-Length: 0
```

And tcpdump from Asterisk:

```
E...W,..@.      .
%].............INVITE sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.37.93.21:5060;branch=z9hG4bK6422ee1e
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "asterisk" <sip:XXXX174264@ip.ip.ip.6>;tag=as43ada6c8
To: <sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6>
Contact: <sip:XXXX174264@10.37.93.21:5060>
Call-ID: 6e8b22967d9c55ea349abb636c0e5263@ip.ip.ip.6
CSeq: 102 INVITE
User-Agent: Linksys/SPA2102-5.2.5
Date: Sat, 19 Jan 2013 18:49:27 GMT
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 333

v=0
o=- 413424664 413424664 IN IP4 10.37.93.21
s=Asterisk PBX 11.2.0
c=IN IP4 10.37.93.21
t=0 0
m=audio 10008 RTP/AVP 0 8 3 111 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
a=rtpmap:111 G726-32/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=silenceSupp:off - - - -
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

00:49:27.073977 IP ip.ip.ip.6.5060 > 10.37.93.21.5060: SIP, length: 348
E..x..@.>.#.....
%]......d..SIP/2.0 100 Trying
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.37.93.21:5060;branch=z9hG4bK6422ee1e
From: "asterisk" <sip:XXXX174264@ip.ip.ip.6>;tag=as43ada6c8
To: <sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6>
Call-ID: 6e8b22967d9c55ea349abb636c0e5263@ip.ip.ip.6
CSeq: 102 INVITE
Contact: <sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6:5060>
Server: MERA MVTS3G v.4.3.0-38t
Content-Length: 0


00:49:27.100102 IP ip.ip.ip.6.5060 > 10.37.93.21.5060: SIP, length: 478
E.....@.>.#?....
%].........SIP/2.0 603 Subscriber account disabled
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.37.93.21:5060;branch=z9hG4bK6422ee1e
From: "asterisk" <sip:XXXX174264@ip.ip.ip.6>;tag=as43ada6c8
To: <sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6>;tag=179071226-3792791650-4082950052-3026001148
Call-ID: 6e8b22967d9c55ea349abb636c0e5263@ip.ip.ip.6
CSeq: 102 INVITE
Contact: <sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6:5060>
Server: MERA MVTS3G v.4.3.0-38t
Reason: Centrex;cause=179;text="Subscriber account disabled"
Content-Length: 0


00:49:27.100295 IP 10.37.93.21.5060 > ip.ip.ip.6.5060: SIP, length: 433
E...W-..@.
.
%]...........#,ACK sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.37.93.21:5060;branch=z9hG4bK6422ee1e
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "asterisk" <sip:XXXX174264@ip.ip.ip.6>;tag=as43ada6c8
To: <sip:474264@ip.ip.ip.6>;tag=179071226-3792791650-4082950052-3026001148
Contact: <sip:XXXX174264@10.37.93.21:5060>
Call-ID: 6e8b22967d9c55ea349abb636c0e5263@ip.ip.ip.6
CSeq: 102 ACK
User-Agent: Linksys/SPA2102-5.2.5
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: Version of Asterisk is 11.2.0

Comment: Ok, I've fixed it with:
`callerid = "\"7XXXX174264\" <7XXXX174264>"` at users.conf

Answer (score 1):

Try change in sip.conf following:

```
[general]
realm=yourprovider-domain-here
useragent = Linksys/PAP2T-5.1.6(LS)
sdpsession= Linksys/PAP2T-5.1.6(LS)
```

Comment: I have try to do it. I didn't notice any changes.

Comment: that mean your provider have better filter then your skill. do same request not posible on asterisk without rewrite, posible using kamailio/opensips but require guru skills in sip.

Comment: i see *s=Asterisk PBX 11.2.0* that mean you not put sdpsession.

Comment: Does setting `realm=provider.com` mean that only users with that domain can register in this aterisk server?

Answer (score 1):

you can use SipAddHeader in dialplan, like

```
SipAddHeader(P-Preferred-Identity: <sip:XXXXXX@10.0.10.10>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two places where you can change these headers.

In your PBX for calls in the sense `PBX -> SPA` you should modify your `sip.conf` file like that:

```
[general]
...
realm = my_realm.com ; This will substitute From: "asterisk"
```

In your SPA2102 for calls in the sense `SPA -> PBX` you have to enter the SPA configuration and change your subscriber information. This is step 5 of this guide: http://www.voipvoip.com/spa-2101/ where it says "Display Name"

Comment: Yes, I know. It is not important for me. I need set headers for my sip provider. In my samples asterisk and spa connect to same sip provider.

Comment: Is that your setup? SIP-provider -> Asterisk -> SPA    Or this? SPA <- SIP-provider -> Asterisk    In the second case, if you need to change the headers for your SIP provider, then this is something only they can do and you should ask them.

Comment: I have try two tests SPA->SIP-provider and Asterisk->SIP-provider. Firsh works fine, second - not works. So, I start to debug and discover differense at packets.

Comment: Please explain what doesn't work. I start to think your problem is no the headers.

Comment: I have add output of tcpdump with same calls from SPA and from Asterisk.

Comment: ´Reason: Centrex;cause=179;text="Subscriber account disabled"´ I think you are using different SIP account configurations in asterisk and SPA. You should post your asterisk sip.conf and your SPA account config page screenshots. I suggest you look at those attentively and check for differences because your provider seems not to recognize the account you are using in Asterisk.

Comment: I can't do this. I don't have login for SPA. I use script to get SIP-account info from Authorization header. It worked fine some time and unexpectly stop to work. Now Asterisk registers fine, but it can't make call. I began to parse packets and discover difference with headers of SPA and Asterisk.

Comment: Does setting realm = my_realm.com mean that only users of type user@my_realm.com can use register to this asterisk server?